# disable mat-step in mat-vertical-stepper

Tags: html, angular-material, angular5

I have 4 `mat-step` in `mat-vertical-stepper.` I want to disable 2nd,3rd & 4th `mat-step` until the 1st `mat-step`'s all fields covered.

I tried:

```
<mat-step label="Step 1">
    <!-- some codes-->
</mat-step>
```

In Step 1 I have a next button and this button is disabled till all fields are covered.

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" style="float:right"
     [disabled]="!DetailsForm.valid" (click)="step2.disabled = false">Next</button>
```

Next is STEP 2:

```
<mat-step label="Step 2" [disabled]="step2.disabled">
```

it shows an error "disabled is not a part of `mat-step`".

Like this, rest two `mat-step` are there. I want to disable 2nd,3rd,4th `mat-step`.

In below case, how can I use `linear`?

```
    <mat-vertical-stepper #stepper>
       <mat-step label="General Details">
           <h4> First Name </h4>
       </mat-step>
       <mat-step label="Education">
           <h4>Highest Education </h4>
       </mat-step>
    </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

And,

```
   <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
     <form [formGroup]="generalDetailsForm">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
           <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
             <input matInput placeholder="First Name" [(ngModel)]="firstName">
           </mat-form-field>
         </div>
      </div>
    </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: use `linear` attribute

Comment: linear , [linear]="true"  did not work :( @ArunDhaJ

Comment: `linear` attribute for `<mat-vertical-stepper>`

Answer (score 11):

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [linear]="true">
<mat-step [completed]="false">
   <!-- set completed = false to disable next step -->
</mat-step>
<mat-step>
   this step would be disable         
</mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution from @delpo and @Matvii should fit your needs.

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper [linear]="true">
 <mat-step
   state="first"
   [completed]="formGroup.valid"
   [editable]="true">
 </mat-step>
 <mat-step state="final">
 </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

This can be achieved by using **[linear]="true"** and disabling the next step with **[completed]="formGroup.valid"** by passing the validity of your FormGroup, so whenever the FormGroup is Valid next step should be enabled/should be able to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to disable step 2 you should use [completed] on step 1, at the same time setting [stepControl] to null, because [stepControl] takes precedence over [completed]

```html
 <mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [linear]="true">
   <!-- step1 -->
   <mat-step
     [stepControl]="shouldNextStepBeDisabled ? null : formGroup"
     [completed]="shouldNextStepBeDisabled ? false : formGroup.valid">
   </mat-step>
   ....
 </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Answer (score 3):

Step-1: Component.ts

`stepDisabled: boolean = true;`

step-2: Component.css

```
::ng-deep .mat-step-header[aria-labelledby="disabled_Resi"] {
  pointer-events: none !important;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

step-3: Component.html

```
  <mat-step [aria-labelledby]="stepDisabled ? 'disabled_Resi' : null" [stepControl]="ResidentalAddressFG"></mat-step>
```

step:4

```
<button mat-stroked-button (click)="stepDisabled = !stepDisabled">{{stepDisabled ? 'Enable' : 'Disable'}} Step</button>
```

Comment: Strange that `aria-labelledby` works... but reading up on the semantic meaning of it, this would be an abuse of the attribute.  `aria-labelledby` should be assigned the ID of another element which describes it, as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby

Comment: Ah, I see `aria-labelledby` and some other attributes are copied from the step onto the header: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/2f9a59a24c0464cbed7f54cbeb5cba73e6007715/src/material/stepper/stepper.html#L69. I think an improvement you can make is to use `aria-label` instead of `labelledby` which expects an element ID.

Answer (score 3):

I had to disable a step depending on a condition.
I created a directive and queried the dom to add a class.

**stylesheet**:

```
.mat-step-disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: #cccccc;
}
```

**Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[step-disable]'
})
export class StepDisableDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() public isDisabled: boolean = true;

 public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
   this.isDisabled? this.disable() : this.enable();
 }
   
  private enable(): void {
    const el:HTMLElement  = this.getElement();
    el.classList.add('mat-step-disabled');
  }

  private disable(): void {
    const el:HTMLElement  = this.getElement();
    el.classList.remove('mat-step-disabled');
  }

  private getElement(): HTMLElement {
    const elements: HTMLCollectionOf<Element> = document.getElementsByClassName(mat-step-header);
    const matStepHeader = elements[0] as HTMLElement;    // Take the first step, you want to pass your index via an Input parameter
    return matStepHeader;
  }    
}
```

**Module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    StepDisableDirective 
  ]
})
export class AppModule{ }
```

**HTML**
Set the directive and it's input parameter

```
<mat-step step-disable [isDisabled]="true" label="Foo">
```

Answer (score 2):

in `mat-step` use `[stepControl]="formName"` and in `.ts` do validation of the form.

Using only `linear` won't help. I was doing wrong. I did not use `[stepControl]`

Answer (score 1):

`mat-vertical-stepper` has no property *disabled* as the exception message says.

try setting `<mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="true">`

after that you need to handle the visibilty of the button as you did. a button has the *disabled* property.

Comment: what if i have mat-vertical-stepper in one <div> and the forms are in another <div>. How to use [linear]="true"?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview and the look for the sample with "Enable linear mode"

Comment: yeah from that only I got to know to use "linear". But in my case i wrote the code in different way. I have `mat-vertical-stepper` in one `<div>` and the form in another `<div>`

Comment: Maybe you can provide a https://stackblitz.com/ template so that we can get a isolated view on your problem?

Comment: code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jyxzim-taufeh?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.html

form is outside of mat-vertical-stepper

Comment: done, have to use both `[stepControl]` and `linear` . I just used only `linear`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone seeing this.

I resolved this with `linear` `completed` attributes.

```
 <mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [linear]="true">
   <mat-step state="state_1" label="label" [completed]="condition">
   </mat-step>
   ....
 </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Use the completed attribute to mark the step as 'completed'

From the docs:

> Alternatively, if you don't want to use the Angular forms, you can
>   pass in the completed property to each of the steps which won't allow
>   the user to continue until it becomes true. Note that if both
>   completed and stepControl are set, the stepControl will take
>   precedence.

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

**Edit**: added example

Comment: Could you explain in details

Answer (score 0):

Using @Hypenate's answer, I just wanted to force the user to stay at the current step while the formGroup (connedted to the current step) is INVALID.

So I made a css definition in styles.css:

```
.mat-element-notclickable{
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #cccccc;
}
```

than in **ngOnInit** I just subscribe to the formGroup's statusChange and disable all the steps as needed:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup.statusChanges.subscribe( newStatus => {
            if( newStatus === 'VALID') {
                Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('mat-step-header')).forEach(element => {
                    element.classList.remove('mat-element-notclickable')
                });
            } else {
                Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('mat-step-header')).forEach(element => {
                    element.classList.add('mat-element-notclickable')
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

(of course, you could just use the header container, and use only one .classList.add and remove, but in other places I will need to enable/disable steps separately)

Answer (score 0):

Use a FormGroup just to allow next step.

Example:
.ts

```
    this.clientForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          client: [this.client, Validators.required],
        });
    this.clientConfigForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          formOk: ['', Validators.required],
          clientForm: this.clientForm
        });
```

.html

```
 <mat-stepper orientation="vertical" linear>

    <mat-step [stepControl]="clientConfigForm">
      <form [formGroup]="clientForm" (ngSubmit)="clientConfigForm.controls.formOk.setValue('ok')">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input type="text" matInput maxlength="10" formControlName="client" class="form-control">
        </mat-form-field>
        
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
            [disabled]="!clientForm.valid">
            Next
          </button>

      </form>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step>
      ...
    </mat-step>
```

Answer (score -7):

Adding attribute class="mat-elevation-z1" worked for me

Comment: Would you care to explain how exactly it fixes the OP's problem?